# How to replace a code in a specific page using sublime text 3?

Tags: editor, sublimetext3

I am using sublime text 3 as my editor and I I dont know if sublime has a capability to find and replace a code in a specific page or current page. For example I have a page that compose of 850 lines and I want to replace a specific variable value. When I used the command <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> it opened the search and replace panel. And in the 'WHERE' it has only options for

```
'Clear', 
'Add Folder', 
'Add Include Filter', 
'Add Exclude Filter', 
'Add Open Folder', 
'Add Open Files'
```

I tried all of them but, where can I find options for a specific page only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the *Key Bindings* preferences file, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> it's binded *panel:find_in_files* whereas <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> it's binded to *panel:replace*.

So, just **use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to replace in the current file**, or you could also use menu *Find > Replace*.

In addition, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> it's a common binding for replace in many other editors.